# Addin a JLabel in a frame?

Tags: java, swing

I have created a `JFrame`, and now I want to add a `JLabel` and textfields in it. Please tell me how to do that. I have used the following code but its not working.

```
JFrame i_frame = new JFrame("Select Locations");
i_from = new JLabel("From");
i_frame.getContentPane().add(i_from);
i_frame.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(2,0)));
i_frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
i_frame.setSize(200,200);
i_frame.setVisible(true);
```

Problem is this code is showing frame window but it is not showing label in it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

That's your first question, later you'll ask:

> *How do I get the value from my text field*

So, I suggest you to take a look at this tutorial

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html

And ask us if you have questions from that tutorial. Using an IDE will simplify your life.

Here's a start anyway:

[image: Java App with Label and Text on OS X]

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;

 public class MyApp {
      public static void main( String [] args ) {
          JFrame frame = new JFrame();
          frame.setBackground( new Color(0,0,0,64 ));
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

          JPanel top = new JPanel();
          top.add( new JLabel("What is your name"){{ 
                setForeground(Color.white);
          }});
          top.add( new JTextField(10) );
          frame.add( top );

         frame.pack();

         frame.setVisible( true );

     }
}
```

**EDIT**
Dismiss this answer. It was posted when the question was rather ambiguous. I'm leaving it as CW for it may be helpful.

<sub>plus OSX frames with alpha background are too cool!</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is the layout being used by the content pane (most likely [JRootPane.RootLayout](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html), A custom layout manager that is responsible for the layout of layeredPane, glassPane, and menuBar ) is not the best. This code should work;

```
JFrame i_frame = new JFrame("Select Locations");
JLabel i_from = new JLabel("From");
i_frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
i_frame.getContentPane().add(i_from);
i_frame.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(2,0)));
i_frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
i_frame.setSize(200,200);
i_frame.setVisible(true);
```

setting a different layout does the trick

Comment: thanks for helping.. now i have tried this layout but even then it is not working.. what shall i do now?

Comment: @S.A.: Whatever you want. Continue adding components to your form. If I were you I would use a visual form editor instead of manually placing things as you seem to be a beginner in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding a second component (Box.createRigidArea) in the same layout position (BorderLayout.CENTER) as the Label.
JFrame.add() results in the same as JFrame.getContentPane().add()...
So the label is being replaced by the RigidArea.
Try this:

```
    JFrame i_frame = new JFrame("Select Locations");
    i_from = new JLabel("From");
    i_frame.getContentPane().add(i_from);
    // i_frame.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(2,0)));
    i_frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    i_frame.setSize(200,200);
    i_frame.setVisible(true);
```

to add more components, change the LayoutManager:

```
    JFrame i_frame = new JFrame("Select Locations");
    JLabel i_from = new JLabel("From");
    Container pane = i_frame.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));  // any LayoutManager you need
    pane.add(i_from);
    pane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(2,0)));  // space after JLabel ?
    i_frame.setSize(200,200);  // better done before setLocationRelativeTo
    i_frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    i_frame.setVisible(true);
```

Note: if you "just" want to add an empty border to your label, use a setBorder() instead of the RigidArea:

```
    i_from.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));
```

[]]

Answer (score 0):

For adding JLabel to JFrame  see  the line of code [see here](http://tutorialdata.com/example/swing/JLabelExample.html)

```
public class JLabelExample extends JFrame {
JLabel jLabel;
public JLabelExample() {
jLabel = new JLabel();
jLabel.setText("tutorialData.com");
jLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
this.add(jLabel);
}
public static void main(String a[]) {
JLabelExample labelExample = new JLabelExample();
labelExample.setSize(250, 200);
labelExample.setTitle("tutorialData.com");
labelExample.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Please refer more on [JFrame](http://tutorialdata.com/example/swing/jframe.html)